# Parse Nested JSON in Spark

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a JSON file whose schema is like this--

```
root
 |-- errorcode: string (nullable = true)
 |-- errormessage: string (nullable = true)
 |-- ip: string (nullable = true)
 |-- label: string (nullable = true)
 |-- status: string (nullable = true)
 |-- storageidlist: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- errorcode: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- errormessage: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- fedirectorList: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- directorId: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- errorcode: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- errordesc: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- metrics: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- portMetricDataList: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: array (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- data: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- ts: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- value: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- errorcode: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- errordesc: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- metricid: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- portid: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- status: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- status: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- metrics: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- status: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- storageGroupList: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- storageid: string (nullable = true)
 |-- sublabel: string (nullable = true)
 |-- ts: string (nullable = true)
```

I am supposed to extract ip,storageid,directorid,metricid,value and ts. In the storageidlist, there is just 1 item, but in the fedirectorList, there are 56 items. But I am unable to parse the JSON beyond storageidlist.

```
scala> val ip_df = spark.read.option("multiline",true).json("FEDirector_port_data.txt")
ip_df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [errorcode: string, errormessage: string ... 6 more fields]

scala> ip_df.select($"storageidlist.storageid").show()
+--------------+
|     storageid|
+--------------+
|[000295700670]|
+--------------+

scala> ip_df.select($"storageidlist.fedirectorList.directorId").show()
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`storageidlist`.`fedirectorList`['directorId']' due to data type mismatch: argument 2 requires integral type, however, ''directorId'' is of string type.;;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`storageidlist` is an array column, so you need to select the first array element and do further selections from that:

```
ip_df.selectExpr("storageidlist[0].fedirectorList.directorId")
```

or

```
ip_df.select($"storageidlist"(0).getField("fedirectorList").getField("directorId"))
```

It's better to specify an array index whenever you work with array type columns. If you don't specify an array index, you can go 1 level deeper and fetch all the corresponding struct elements in the next level, but you can't go further, as shown in your question.

Comment: But I didn't need to index it to get storageid. It worked fine there and returned 000295700670. Then why am I required to index it to get directorId?

Comment: @Anakata see the edited answer. You need to index the array column if you want to go deeper than 1 level. storageid is just below the array column level, so you can select it, but directorId is 2 levels below the array column level, so you need to specify an array index.

Answer (score 1):

```
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
file = "<s3path>/<json_file_name.json>"
schema_path = "<s3path>/<json_schame_name.json>"
json_schema = spark.read.json(schema_path, multiLine=True)
df = sqlContext.read.json(file,json_schema.json_schema,multiLine=True)
#display(df)
df.createOrReplaceTempView("temptable")
#example UDF
def parse_nested_list(nested_list):
    parsed_str = []
    if nested_list:
        for item_list in nested_list:
            if item_list:
                for item in item_list:
                    if item:
                        parsed_str.append(item)
    return "|".join(parsed_str)
def parse_arrs(x):
    if x:
        return "| ".join(
        ", ".join(i for i in e if i is not None) for e in x if e is not None
    )
    else:
        ""
sqlContext.udf.register("parse_nested_list", parse_nested_list)
sqlContext.udf.register("parse_arrs", parse_arrs)
structured_df =sqlContext.sql("select parse_nested_list(column1.column2) as column3, parse_arrs(column1) as column2 from temptable")
display(structured_df)
```

To fetch the nested array, list, dictionaries. You will have to write a UDF to get the nested values and register it to pyspark so that you can use them in sparksql coding.